# Citation of the table or illustration made by myself

Tags: citations, citation-style

I wanted to state the source of the illustration I made by myself. The illustration shows the structure of the company, which is based on my research and a number of other sources. What is the best way to state the source? Can I just write *Author* or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Has this illustration been published before?

Comment: No, it was not published before.

Answer (score 5):

There are three options:

1) It is yours and you made it from scratch especially for this publication. You do not need to cite anything. If reviewers or the editor ask, mention that it is yours.

2) It is yours and you based it on some other illustration X that was published by someone else. Then mention that you based it on X and cite X.

3) It is yours and you published it before. If you are sure you are allowed to re-publish it by the original publisher then cite the original publication. If you are not 100% sure, consult the original publisher about their rules for re-publishing figures.

Answer (score 1):

Cite it like it's not yours, i.e. the same way you would cite anything coming from anyone else.

Comment: That does not work if this has not been published before.

Comment: @skymningen "Blah blah blah (Smith, personal communication) _or_ (Smith, unpublished) _or_ (Smith, in preparation)" etc.

Answer (score -1):

If it's yours, there is no need for citation!

If it was published before, you should cite the first publication of it (of course while respecting all copyright rules as always when you are using illustrations).

Comment: If it was published before by the author, there might be some rules about re-publishing it You would have to consult the original publisher (they now have rights to it).

Comment: @skymningen This was so obvious to me I did not mention it... I added a sentence on that.

Comment: @skymningen they *may* now have rights to it (or more strictly, own and control the copyright on it). This is, thankfully, not quite as ubiquitous as it used to be.